# Formulario detalle tabla cuando ajusto a modo responsive se borra las filas de la tabla

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
-- Tengo 2 formularios, la cual el 1er formulario (1ra imagen) es un modal que pasa los productos al 2do formulario

-- Después de pasar los productos del modal a la tabla inserta filas en la tabla hasta ahí lo hace correctamente bien, el tema es cuando ajusto o le doy el comportamiento de responsive o la vista de celular o Tablet es decir que se ajuste a cualquier dispositivo las filas de las tablas desaparecen esta parte no se como hacerlo, lo hice de esta manera pero no me sale. (ver 2da imagen

```js
 var artite = 0; var artimp = 0;
 $(document).on("click", ".agrpro", function () {
     row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
     artite = artite + 1;
         artcod = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()); 
     var artmod = row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
     var artdes = row.find("td:eq(2)").text();
     var artmar = row.find("td:eq(3)").text();
     var artpsi = row.find("td:eq(4)").text();
     var artpci = row.find("td:eq(5)").text();
     var artsto = row.find("td:eq(8)").text(); //-- Stock
     var artcan = $("#cantAdd_" + artcod).val();        
     var total = parseFloat((artcan * artpsi).toFixed(2));
     var artplb = row.find("td:eq(6)").text();
     var totlib = parseFloat((artcan * artplb).toFixed(2));
     var artpkg = parseFloat(row.find("td:eq(7)").text());
     var totklg = parseFloat((artcan * artpkg).toFixed(2));
     var cotimp = (artcan - artsto)

     if (artcan > artsto) {
         artimp = cotimp ;
     } else {
         artimp = 0;
     }

     //for (let artite = 0; artite < 5; artite++) {
     //    console.log(artite); // Imprime los números del 0 al 4
     //}

     var contbod =
            `<tr class="table-responsive-sm">
             <td class='text-center cotite'>${artite}</td>
             <td class='text-center'>${artcod}</td>
             <td>${artmod}</td>
             <td>${artdes}</td>
             <td>${artmar}</td>
             <td>${artpsi}</td>
             <td>${artpci}</td>
             <td>${artsto}</td>
             <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class="cotcan">${artcan}</td>
             <td>${artimp}</td>
             <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class='subtotal'>${total}</td>
             <td>${artplb}</td>
             <td class="cottlb">${totlib}</td>
             <td>${artpkg}</td>
             <td  class="cottkg">${totklg}</td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="btn_remove btn btn-xs btn-danger ml-1"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>Eliminar</button></td>
             </tr>`;
     $("#tabCot tbody").append(contbod);
/*     document.getElementById("TxtSer").value = final;*/
    /* $('#tabCot').dataTable();*/
     calsum()
     elifil()
 })
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                @*<table id="tabCot" style="display: inline-block" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%">*@
                <table id="tabCot" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover display compact" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Cod.</th>
                            <th scope="col">Modelo</th>
                            <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                            <th scope="col">Marca</th>
                            <th scope="col">Pre.Uni.</th>
                            <th scope="col">P.U con IGV</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stock</th>
                            <th scope="col">Cant.</th>
                            <th scope="col">Impor.</th>
                            @*<th scope="col" ; class="subtotal">Tot. Vta</th>*@
                            <th scope="col">Tot. Vta</th>
                            <th scope="col">P. LB</th>
                            <th scope="col">T. Peso LB</th>
                            <th scope="col">P. KG</th>
                            <th scope="col">T. Peso KG</th>
                            <th scope="col">..</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    <tfoot align="left">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: lemonchiffon; font-weight: bold">0</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; font-weight: bold">0</td>
                            <td></td>
                            @*<td align="right" colspan="10">Total US$</td>*@
                            <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; font-weight: bold">0</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; font-weight: bold">0</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; font-weight: bold">0</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                    @*<tfoot align="right">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4"><span class="pull-right">Sub Total $</span></td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">0.00</span></td>
                                </tr>
                        </tfoot>*@
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="display: inline-block">
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-0">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <label class="txt-rad input-group-text bg-secondary text-white" for="inputGroupSelect02">Can. Item.</label>
                                </div>
                                <input id="TxtIte" name="CocIte" disabled readonly type="text" class="txt-rad form-control form-control-sm">

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <label class="txt-rad input-group-text bg-secondary text-white" for="inputGroupSelect02">Can. Arti.</label>
                                </div>
                                <input id="TxtArt" name="CocTar" disabled readonly type="text" class="txt-rad form-control form-control-sm">

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <label class="txt-rad input-group-text bg-secondary text-white" for="inputGroupSelect02">T. Peso LBs</label>
                                </div>
                                <input id="TxtTlb" name="CocTlb" disabled readonly type="text" class="txt-rad form-control form-control-sm">

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <label class="txt-rad input-group-text bg-secondary text-white" for="inputGroupSelect02">T. Peso KGs</label>
                                </div>
                                <input id="TxtTkg" name="CocTkg" disabled readonly type="text" class="txt-rad form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="display: inline-block">
                        
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text form-control-sm">Moneda ......:</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="US$">
                                <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="S/.">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text form-control-sm">Sub Total ....:</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="0.0" id="TxtDst" name="CocDst">
                                    <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="0.0" id="TxtSst" name="CocSst">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text form-control-sm">IGV 18% ......:</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="0.0" id="TxtDig" name="CocDig">
                                    <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="0.0" id="TxtSig" name="CocSig">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text form-control-sm">Monto Total :</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="0.0" id="TxtDmt" name="CocDmt">
                                    <input type="text" disabled readonly class="txt-may txtcal form-control form-control-sm" value="0.0" id="TxtSmt" name="CocSmt">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

)